# Compare audio files for "Voice Authentication"

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication, voice

I'm developing an Iphone app. This application is used for storing user's personal data.
For the security purpose we are looking to provide a new feature in our application, user can access the data after logged-in to the application.
The issue is we need to provide **"voice Authentication"**. Means, user can save a word like "hi" as his password by recording it. If he needs to log-in to our application he should speak the word "hi". And the two sounds are compared and if they match then user will be authenticated and log-in will be allowed.
Is such a application is possible ?
Is it possible to compare the voices in Iphone?

I researched on these links, but didn't get an Idea. Please help me.
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/musicaudio/reference/CoreAudioDataTypesRef/Reference/reference.html

Comment: If you are new to iOS dev, something as complex as voice recognition software will probably be very difficult. I'm not an expert myself, but I'm not aware of any off-the-shelf voice recognition code that would be useful too you either. Best of luck.