# Voice authentication in iOS SDK

Tags: ios, voice-recognition, biometrics

I want to use a user's voice as his password to authenticate him. I have googled and found many third party API's providing solutions for voice authentication. I have 2 questions however,

1. Does iOS SDK provide support to make voice authentication system using built-in API's e.g. CoreAudio etc.?
2. Are there any third party API's which don't require voice recordings to be uploaded to there server for authentication. (I want the app to work without internet)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020689/compare-audio-files-for-voice-authentication

Comment: I have already read that post of yours but there are no answers to it. Just wanted to know if it could be done without using any third party framework, and secondly, if some third party provides the solution without uploading the audio to there servers. Thanks.

Comment: In my research I couldn't get a built-in way to do that. Also I couldn't get a solution for that (Me was also searching a offline version), so if you get a solution, please feel free to answer my question also :)