# iOS | Can I use SiriKit to authenticate user with his/her voice?

Tags: ios, voice-recognition, sirikit

I am brainstorming and came up with an idea of authenticating user with his/her voice. Googling around didn't give me anything I need. I've found some resources about voice authentication but can I do it with SiriKit? That's the question. So I'm here. Thank you.

Comment: Siri can’t identify the user, most of the implementation of Siri is on the cloud, the only thing close is that when “hey siri” is activated the device asks the user to say few phrases in order to recognize the “Hey Siri” faster. Check out this document: https://machinelearning.apple.com/2017/10/01/hey-siri.html

Comment: My research says if I can record the voice of the user, I can compare with another voice recording to authenticate. So, can SiriKit send the voice it hears to the app? My research says SiriKit cannot do that. I have to record the voice via a button click or something like that. But I'm asking. in case of I might miss something.

Comment: I'm not an expert in this specific issue but it seem highly unlikely (due to Apple's privacy policies) that Siri will send the user voice to an app

Comment: Thank you @inspector_60 for your help.

Comment: should I write an answer? Did I helped ?

Comment: No need. I will write one according my googling and your comments.

Answer (score 0):

After my googling and the help from @inspector_60 here are my conclusions for now:

- To voice authentication you have to record voices and compare 2 recordings.
- You cannot record voice and pass it to your app via SiriKit. So you cannot do voice authentication via SiriKit.
- But you can record voice with a button click or something like that. Here is a SOQ : [Compare audio files for "Voice Authentication"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020689/compare-audio-files-for-voice-authentication)
- Instead of voice authentication, you can make Siri ask for TouchID or FaceID authentication. The main problem here is (at least in my project) you cannot select which fingerprint / faceprint on the phone has permission. Ex: My phone has my and my GF's fingerprints. But I want to let the application authenticate with my fingerprints only. This is not achievable for now.